# Reconnect using Mule 3.5 db connector

Tags: mule, mule-component

I'm in the process of upgrading my flows to Mule 3.5.1 (from 3.4.1).  I am trying to replace the deprecated jdbc-ee:connector with the new db connector.  For the database, we are using Microsoft sql server.  There isn't a predefined configuration for MS SQL Server, so I'm using the db:generic-config configuration.  Does anyone know how to configure reconnection strategies with the new DB config?  I'm finding the documentation is very sparse.  Using the old jdbc-ee:connector, you can simply specify the strategy as a child element.

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="myDbConnector" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" dataSource-ref="myDatasource" doc:name="Database">
    <reconnect-forever blocking="false" frequency="2000" />
</jdbc-ee:connector>
```

According to the mule documentation, "The Properties pane for almost every global endpoint and global connector that appears in the Studio interface features a Reconnection tab, as pictured below:", but I guess the new DB connector doesn't fall into the category of "almost every"!

Comment: Yes .. you are right .. there is no clear documentation on this .. I guess as of now there might not be a way to configure reconnection strategies on Mule DB 3.5

Comment: I received an answer from Mule support in case anyone else runs into this problem.  The reconnect strategies are not supported on the new connectors in this version.  They said they will be supported in Mule 3.6 when that comes out.

Comment: Then we cant achieve this with 3.5.1 in anyways!!! I'm running on same Problem :(. If you used any other ways. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

DB reconnection was added in Mule 3.6.0: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7741