# Not able to do retry with 'db: generic-config' in 3.5.1 version Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Since DB (Using db: generic-config) Global Connector don't have reconnect strategy. I'm externally trying to set the  reconnect Strategy as mentioned in the link http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/35X/Configuring+Reconnection+Strategies. After selecting the configuration, it allows me to set the reconnect, once after selecting. It is giving error like

```
 'Element: is not allowed to be child of element configuration'
```

Please find the config

```
<configuration >
<reconnect></reconnect>
</configuration>
```

Do any one experiences as above. While listing, the reconnect option found  under configuration  but it is throwing error.  Could any one help me to resolve the issue.
If this option won't  work , please correct me with other options how to retry for . I'm trying this option in order to retry for my DB.

Referred this link also:[Reconnect using Mule 3.5 db connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875370/reconnect-using-mule-3-5-db-connector). No solution to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Default reconnection strategy worked fine for me running Mule 3.5.1 EE when used with ActiveMQ connection but did not work when used with JDBC connection (db:generic-config).

AnypointStudio XML parser do complain that reconnect element cannot be a child of configuration element `'Element: is not allowed to be child of element configuration'` but the server started without any errors.

Based on the XSD, reconnect is a valid child of configuration. Not sure why AnypointStudio complains about that:

https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/schemadocs/schemas/mule_xsd/elements/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and have given a trial for issue.  Are you able to refer the reconnection Strategy in db:generic-config. If so can be please provide the sample snippet here. It will be more helpful for me to resolev my issue. Thanks.

Comment: No. I couldn't add reconnection child element to db:generic-config.

Comment: oops :( . We can't do retry for db: generic-config?. No other possible way?. Do you have any clue for this.